# Ruby on Rails 3.2.17 | How can i write a RegEx for UK Currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I've spent a long time searching through the questions on stack overflow and I've found none that link to UK currency and none that actually work.

So my question is how can I express a format check for currency in my item.rb file that validates for currency.

Here is what i currently have

**Item.RB**

```
has_attached_file :picture

validates :name, :presence => true
validates :name, :length => {:maximum => 20}
validates :description, :presence => true
validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 200}
validates :price, :presence => true
validates :price, :format => {:with  => /^\d+??(?\.\d{0,2})/ }
validates :position, :presence => true 
validates :position, :uniqueness => true
validates :visible, :presence => true
```

The Reg ex isn't working and I don;t know enough about it to understand why? I'm sure its simple as hell but can you give me a RegEx i can put in the format check for Uk Currency.

Would be ever so grateful

( a pound sign followed by any number of digits before a decimal point and 0 - 2 digits after that. )

-Nboaram

Comment: Can you provide examples of what is valid and what is not?

Comment: Alright I think the negative down voting is unfair. I have thoroughly looked into this. If you feel you wanna down vote it at least comment and justify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
^(\d+\.\d{0,2})
```

I do know have the pound sign but that can be added in front.

Rubular can aid you with this.

http://rubular.com/

Comment: Thanks for the website suggestion